# My method needs to return a string, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java

My program is complaining that the method is not returning a string. What am I doing wrong with my return statement? Thanks

```
 public String diskGame( int n)
 {   
     char fromPole = 'A';
     char toPole = 'B';


     //base case
     if (n == 1)  //there is only 1 disk left
     {
        return( "Move White from " + fromPole + " to " + toPole + "/n");

     }
 }
```

Comment: Think about what happens if `n != 1`.

Comment: if n is not 1 then there is no string being returned

Comment: Then you should add `return null` or something at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` statement is in an `IF` which is an issue.

`IF n is not equal to 1` the program will not reach return statement and hence the error.

Add a return statement

```
     public String diskGame( int n)
     {   
         char fromPole = 'A';
         char toPole = 'B';
         String result = "";

         //base case
         if (n == 1)  //there is only 1 disk left
         {
           result = "Move White from " + fromPole + " to " + toPole + "/n"

         }
       return result;
     }
```

Obviously you can set the default value of `result` to anything you want.In case, `n!=1` it will return `""` in my code, add anything you want for user understanding, don't leave it blank

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed your code :D

```
public String diskGame( int n) throws MyFirstException
 {   
     char fromPole = 'A';
     char toPole = 'B';
     //base case
     if (n == 1)  //there is only 1 disk left
     {
        return( "Move White from " + fromPole + " to " + toPole + "/n");

     }
     throw new MyFirstException("N is not equal to one");
 }
```

And the MyFirstException implementation:

```
public class MyFirstException extends Exception
{
   public MyFirstException(String message)
   {
       super(message);
    }
}
```

Example  usage:

```
//code
n = 500;
try
{
   // code
   System.out.println(diskGame(n));
   // code
}
catch (MyFirstException e)
{
    System.out.println("WTF: "+e.getMessage());
    // code to handle the exception, the System.out.println or logging are optional
}
```

Basically your code does not know what to do when N has a value that is not 1.

by trowing an exception, instead of a null or an empty string, you can handle **elegantly** this thing that should not happen using a try-catch statement. **It will make your code much easier to read and understand** that checking if the returned string is null or the empty string. [Further reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

Comment: Code only answer are not good for the site. Please explain the problem in the code and how to solve it. In this case, it will be good to explain why throwing an exception is better than returning an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle other scenario where n is not equal to 1. The method has to return error string or "".